# Karma-commonjs can't find my top-level node_modules

Tags: node.js, karma-runner, commonjs

I'm trying to use [karma-commonjs](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs), but I can't seem to get it to lookup packages properly. You can see that [on this line](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs/blob/master/lib/plugin.js#L19), modules are looked up under `./node_modules` if there's no config pragma for it in your `karma.conf.js`.

I can clearly tell that my package is under `./node_modules`. Does karma's file server not serve from that directory? How should browser-oriented test code with Karma include an npm module? Any help with this would be tremendous.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?